# Create a column based on the values of another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this first dataframe df :

```
                       cur_cost_id   cur_sales_id  product_description
date_facture                                                      
2020-01-01 00:20:09            2             1                  io
2020-01-01 00:25:12            2             2                  io
2020-01-01 00:25:35            2             1                  io
2020-01-01 00:25:50            2             4                  io
2020-01-01 00:25:52            2             2                  io
```

Using another dataframe below on exchange rates I created the avg average:

```
avg=df.mean(axis=1)

2020-05-27  2020-04-23  2020-06-12  2020-03-31  2020-03-30  2020-06-19  \
AUD    1.507142    1.570553    1.454972    1.639923    1.633225    1.450580   
BGN    1.779456    1.815633    1.730184    1.785141    1.772521    1.744692   
EUR    5.338823    5.446157    5.076787    5.202720    5.121533    5.354951
```

I try to add a column to the first dataframe so that if `cur_sales_id=1` then the value in the new column is `avg['EUR']`.

I tried this :

```
def taux_change(row):
   if row['cur_sales_id'] == 1:
       val = avg['EUR']
   return val

df['Taux_change'] = df.apply(taux_change, axis=1)
```

But I have this error :

> ("local variable 'val' referenced before assignment", 'occurred at
> index 2020-01-01 00:20:09')

Somebody could explain me why please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def taux_change(row):
   if row['cur_sales_id'] == 1:
       val = avg['EUR']
   return val

df['Taux_change'] = df.apply(taux_change, axis=1)
```

you should give a tab to the line `return val` because it returns the val from the function. other wise it would be like a normal code flow.

Answer (score 1):

In your function do you not assign a value for val if `row['cur_sales_id'] != 1`.

A better way to write your function would be

```
def taux_change(row):
    if row['cur_sales_id'] == 1:
        val = avg['EUR']
    else:
        val = None
    return val

df['Taux_change'] = df.apply(taux_change, axis=1)
```

An alternate way would be:

```
df.loc[df['cur_sales_id'] == 1,'Taux_change'] = avg['EUR']
```

And even better might be using the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function and create a dictionary of the average exchange rates `avg_xr_dict` and then:

```
df["Taux_change"] = df["cur_sales_id"].map(avg_xr_dict)
```